# How do i get this search method to work for sub-classes as well as the the super-class?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

This is a piece of a class thats called Player. findItem() is the method that's used to return an Item from the HashMap "items".

```
public class Player extends Character {
    private String type;
    private int carryWeight;
    private HashMap<String, Item> items;


    public Item findItem(String search) {
        return this.items.get(search);
    }
```

This method has been working fine until now.
Now, i have a subclass for Item, called Weapon.

```
public class Weapon extends Item{
    private int damage;

    public Weapon(String name, String description, String action, int value, int weight, int damage){
        super(name, description, action, value, weight);
        this.damage = damage;
     }

    public int getDamage(){
        return damage;
}
```

}

I can add a Weapon to the items HashMap in Player because Weapon is just an extension of Item. I can also use findItem() to find the  weapon in the HashMap, but it returns it as an Item and not a Weapon. This makes it so that i cannot use the getDamage() method from the weapon subclass. Does anyone see a quick solution to my problem? Im pretty sure its something im missing about inheritance.

I tried writing this method, but it says it cannot convert Item to Weapon:

```
public Weapon findWeapon(String search){
    for (Weapon weapon : items.values()){
        something somthing
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use instanceof to sort out Weapon instances.  For example:

```
public Weapon findWeapon(String search){
  for (Item item : items.values()) {
    if(weapon instanceof Weapon) {
      Weapon weapon = (Weapon)item;
      <something somthing>
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick for me. Instanceof seems to be something i've overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Mark Bidewell's answer, you can make it more interesting with `Enum` like this:

```
public class Item {

    // ...
    // ...
    public enum ItemType {
        WEAPON, ARMOR, FOOD, ITEM;
    }

    public ItemType getItemType() {
        return ItemType.ITEM;
    }

}

class Weapon extends Item {

    private int damage;

    public Weapon(String name, String description, String action, int value, int weight, int damage) {
        super(name, description, action, value, weight);
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    public int getDamage() {
        return damage;

        @Override
        public ItemType getItemType () {
            return ItemType.WEAPON;
        }

}

    // you can just cast like this
public Weapon findWeapon(String search) {
    for (Item item : items.values()) {
        if (item.getItemType().equals(ItemType.WEAPON)) {
            Weapon weapon = (Weapon) item;
            // ...
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Using `Enum` to check what kind of the item also fits your game logic, makes the program more robust and when other programmers use your API, they know EXACTLY what kinds of items there are without looking at your source code.

Comment: Great suggestion! I'll look into this, although its new to me. Seems simple enough though :) 

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @mRambech It can get even more interesting, I hope it helps. I also updated my answer with more info as to why it is very important to use `Enum` in your case.